# Accidentally removed all access for authenticated users to an external hard drive. Is it possible to revert this change?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I was trying to restrict access to my `G:` hard drive for guests and accidentally removed all access to the hard drive for all authenticated users. I am not able to access the drive or take ownership of it even with my admin account. I am not able to edit the permission using the `Security tab`:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/99fd5f329ab843a7ecb77e1c8bd15ebe.png]

Does someone know if it's possible to revert this as I have some important stuff on that drive?

Comment: Can you show the "Advanced" tab? How were you trying to "take ownership" and why do you think it did not succeed?